# Create an array in asm java compiler

Tags: java, assembly, compiler-construction, bytecode

Iam trying to create an array of integers using bytecode instructions

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Did you look at the `anewarray` or `newarray` instructions?

Comment: Yes but the problem is i do not know how to syntax it for example it doesn't say how to put the size of the array.

Comment: @Tony.  You may write actual java code, compile and then use javap (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) to get the bytecode.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the array is popped off the stack, so you need to push it onto the stack first.

To create a 1000 element array for instance, you could do something like

```
sipush 1000
newarray int
```

Edit: I just noticed that there's a standard lib function to fill arrays. That makes things much easier.

```
sipush 1000
newarray int
dup
iconst_1
invokestatic java/util/Arrays fill ([II)V
```

Comment: ok thanks. And if you want for example to initialise the array with the number 1 after the creation what i will have to do?

Comment: You mean initialize every element of the array to 1? You'd have to write a loop.

Comment: Can you show me some code using instructions of asm to understand how to do it?

Comment: @Tony I just posted an example of how to do it with `Arrays.fill`.